# Carregar dados de uma action para outra

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Eu tenho uma `Action HttpGet`, onde essa `Action` recebe dois parâmetros, `dataInicial`, e `dataFinal`, isso gera um relatório, na mesma `Action`. só que eu gostaria de enviar esses dados (Lista), para uma outra tela, onde já está pronto para impressão em tamanho A4, gostaria de saber apenas como enviar esses dados para essa outra view, já tentei usar o `return RedirectToAction("RelatorioTotalPorDatadois", vrDb);` mas não deu certo.

```
public ActionResult RelatorioData(DateTime? dataInicio, DateTime? dataFim)
{
    ViewBag.dataInicial = dataInicio;
    ViewBag.dataFinal = dataFim;

    if (dataInicio == null && dataFim == null)
    {
        var vrDb = db.VrDb.Where(v => v.DataSolicitacao >= dataInicio && v.DataSolicitacao <= dataFim).OrderBy(v => v.DataSolicitacao).ToList();
        return View(vrDb);
    }

    else
    {
        var vrDb = db.VrDb.Where(v => v.DataSolicitacao >= dataInicio && v.DataSolicitacao <= dataFim && v.Situacao == Situacao.Finalizado).OrderBy(v => v.DataSolicitacao).ToList();
        var data = dataInicio;
        var dataF = dataFim;

        var tot = db.VrDb.Sum(v => v.Mv.Consumo); //Mostra o Total gasto

        if (tot == 0)
        {
            ViewBag.Total = "0";
        }
        else
        {
            ViewBag.Total = tot;
        }

        var abastecido = db.VrDb.Sum(v => v.Mv.CombustivelAbastecido);
        if (abastecido == 0)
        {
            ViewBag.Abastecido = "0";
        }
        else
        {
            ViewBag.Abastecido = abastecido;
        }

        ViewBag.ListaDb = vrDb;
        return View(vrDb);
        //return RedirectToAction("RelatorioTotalPorDatadois", vrDb);

    }
}
```

Essa é a tela dessa `Action`:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas eu gostaria de colocar um botão nessa tela, com a opção Imprimir:
Onde esses dados fossem carregados para outra tela

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: editei sua pergunta para deixar mais direta, lembre-se que não há pergunta idiota!!, agora sobre o seu problema, mais tarde tento elaborar uma resposta, mas pelo que vi, você clica em botão, é carregada uma tela com a lista e nessa tela com a lista você deseja mais um botão para imprimir, correto?

Comment: Sim, Exatamente.

Comment: porque o `RedirectToAction` não funcionou? Ele não está transportando a `ViewModel` ou é porque você não conseguiu identificar quando é para ser uma impressão ou apenas a exibição na tela?

Comment: Quando eu uso o redirectoAction, eu passo a view e o objeto. Porém essa é a URL que aparece: http://localhost:49756/Vr/RelatorioTotalPorDatadois?Capacity=4&Count=4.
E o erro, é o mesmo de quando não encontra uma pagina: Erro de Servidor no Aplicativo '/'.
 return RedirectToAction("RelatorioTotalPorDatadois", vrDb);
Quando as telas, quando eu uso o  RedirectToAction, a primeira tela apenas aparece para que eu possa preencher com a data, e quando eu envio, já redireciona para a segunda tela, onde já está no formato A4.

Comment: Ahh é que nesse caso você deveria utilizar `return View("RelatorioTotalPorDatadois", vrDb);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para conseguir passar objetos entre as Views ou tem que ser:

TempData usando keep() e peek() ou usando Session, porque a view apenas reflete as informações que são enviadas pela action.
Para passar objetos de View para View só conheço essas opções.